# How to set the minimum size to restrict the resizing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i have used the user control. i have also set the minimum size to the user control. i have used the following codes to enable the resizing..

```
 private const int cGrip = 16;      // Grip size
 private const int cCaption = 32;   // Caption bar height;
 protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
 {
     if (m.Msg == 0x84)
     { 
         // Trap WM_NCHITTEST
         System.Drawing.Point pos = new System.Drawing.Point(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);
         pos = this.PointToClient(pos);
         if (pos.Y < cCaption)
         {
             m.Result = (IntPtr)2;  // HTCAPTION
             return;
         }
         if (pos.X >= this.MinimumSize.Width - cGrip && pos.Y >= this.MinimumSize.Height - cGrip)
         {
              m.Result = (IntPtr)17; // HTBOTTOMRIGHT
              return;
          }
     }
     base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

But its not working to set the minimum size. its resizing to size as 0.please refer the below image. i want to set the minimum size to restrict the resizing. please suggest any solutions?

[image]

Comment: Why dont you just set it in designer for the `UserControl`?

Comment: WM_NCHITTEST is not where you set the minimum size. You would need to do that in response to WM_GETMINMAXINFO. Or better yet, in WinForms, you'd just set the [MinimumSize property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.minimumsize.aspx). Let WM_NCHITTEST take care of itself.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't completely understood what you are trying to achieve. But, if you are populating your UserControl in a Windows Forms, simply set the MinimumSize property of the control. If that's not right, please explain more and share screenshots & code snippets in order to help us understand.